# MYSQL Foreign key incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql

Have an error where my first foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed. I'm waiting to hear back from my lecturer if she can spot the issue but thought I'd ask here

My SQL query is as follows

```
CREATE DATABASE rugby;
USE rugby;

CREATE TABLE address(
address_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
address_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (address_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE team(
team_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
team_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
team_Year INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(team_ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE person(
person_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
phone INT NOT NULL,
address_ID INT NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
photo BLOB,
PRIMARY KEY(person_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(address_ID) REFERENCES address(address_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I have followed how we were taught but can't spot the issue.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table `person` you have defined `address_ID` as `NOT NULL`, but
when you define the `FOREIGN KEY` you set:

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

which contradicts the `NOT NULL` definition.

Comment: I guess you have to remove the `NOT NULL` definition.